# When I try to use useKeepGroupedColumnsHidden in MUI's DataGrid, it is throwing the error props.apiRef.current.subscribeEvent is not a function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

When I add the following code snippet to my react component:

```
  const apiRef = useGridApiRef();
  const initialState = useKeepGroupedColumnsHidden({
    apiRef,
    initialState: {
      rowGrouping: {
        model: ['datetime'],
      },
    },
  });
```

it gives the error `props.apiRef.current.subscribeEvent is not a function`

This [github discussion](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/2904) says to fix the issue is to use DataGrid Pro/Premium, but am indeed importing the objects from the premium import:

```
import {
  useKeepGroupedColumnsHidden,
  useGridApiRef,
} from '@mui/x-data-grid-premium';
```

codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-satoshi-fmszwu?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I was not passing in apiRef to the DataGridPremium component

Before (not working, throwing `props.apiRef.current.subscribeEvent is not a function`):

```
  <DataGridPremium
    rows={rows}
    columns={columns}
    initialState={initialState}
  />
```

After (working):

```
  <DataGridPremium
    rows={rows}
    columns={columns}
    initialState={initialState}
    apiRef={apiRef}
  />
```